# MATLAB: How to make the Hermitean matrix from specific complex vectors?

Tags: matlab, complex-numbers

**Is given**:
stationary mass  `ms=1;` 
Eta-constant  `eta=0.45;` 
variable number of repetitions, e.g.  `N=5;` 
omega  `OM=sqrt(ks/ms);` 
angular frequency  `om=eta*OM;` 
time period  `T=2*pi/om;` 
upper bound  `TTT=1.5;`
variable for creating function  `t=0:0.001:TTT;`

I made a function like that:

```
kt=zeros(size(t));
for j=1:2*N+1
    n= j-(N+1);    
    if n==0
        k(j)=ks/2;
    else
        k(j)=i/pi/n;
    end
    kt=kt+k(j)*exp(i*n*om*t);
end
```

It’s a **Sawtooth** wave and there is my **problem**. From the complex vector kt with value 1x1501 double I have to make the **Hermitean** matrix for **variable N**. This means that N can be 5, can be 50, 100, etc. The matrix should look like (picture):
[image: Hermitean matrix]

Where k1 is k for N=1, k0 is k for N=0 or k-1 is k for N=-1. Size of matrix is 2*N+1 and 2*N+1.

*Thank you for your help and responding!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [Toeplitz matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix), you can use the [`toeplitz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/toeplitz.html) command to generate the matrix above. In the general case, this would have been written as:

```
H = toeplitz(kt(N:end), kt(1:N + 1))
```

where the first *N* values in `kt` correspond to *k*<sub>-*N*</sub>, ... *k*<sub>-1</sub>, and the last *N* + 1 values are *k*<sub>0</sub>, ... *k*<sub>*N*</sub>. However, since `H` is Hermitian, this can be simplified to:

```
H = toeplitz(kt(N:end));
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew that is specific matrix, but I couldn't remember the name :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
k=[1 2+i 3+i 4+i 5+i];
N=7;
M=diag(k(1)*ones(N,1));

for j=1:length(k)-1
    M=M+diag(k(j+1)*ones(N-j,1),j)+diag(conj(k(j+1))*ones(N-j,1),-j)
end;
```

Here N should be equal or greater than the length of k array

Comment: Thank you, it's usefull too ;)